# YouTube Data API Error. (403) Access Not Configured. Quota limit issue

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api, quota, google-console-developer

We got the request from google to submit YouTube API Audit form and we have submitted with all information but it seems our Console project with YouTube Data API still not activated properly because of status display "Active" but the daily quota is blank.

When I am going to update daily quota with any number but it seems set with blank on page refresh and we are not able to make any single request successful.

We are working with this console project and YouTube API for the last 5 years without any issue but in the last few months we are getting so many issues like first, we have verified OAuth screen with requested scopes and it has taken 20-25 days in the verification process and published. Now, facing another issue about limit quota and audit form.

Right now we are getting below error as attached in screenshot while going to authenticate my google account with the permission of Manage YouTube data API.

There is no contact support provided and I have submitted form 3 times but no back reply from support so waiting since 1 month to get work as normal.

Let me know if anyone has idea!

**Error**:

```
Error calling GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=contentDetails&mine=true: 
(403) Access Not Configured. YouTube Data API has not been used in project xxxxxxx before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting 
https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/youtube.googleapis.com/overview?project=xxxxxxx then retry. 
If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry.
```

[image]

Comment: I caught the same problem. Moreover, my project was deleted without my knowledge, because of this, such an error. And now, when I created a new project and changed the access key, my limit burns out in a couple of minutes, although there are much fewer requests and everything worked for several years

Comment: Yes, Exactly ! No support provided by Google and just forwarding to use stackoverflow.

Answer (score 3):

> Access Not Configured. Quota limit issue

This means that you do not have any quota to use the API.  You need to apply for an additional quota within the Google developer console. It took me about three months to get a quota on my project.

This is not the same as going through the verification process all though it is similar.   Unfortunately, you must have missed an email you were probably notified a while ago that Google was locking down the quotas and you should apply before losing the quota on your existing project.

There is no support other than going though the form and simply waiting until google choices to grant you some quota or they tell you they wont.  This is the price of developing with a free api google gets chose how they want to allow us to access things.